# why does 5 == 3|7 is TRUE in R

Tags: r

```
3 == 7|5
```

I know R uses "==" in precedence of "||, but what does the code above actually mean and why it gives a TRUE in return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explanation:

`|` is a logical or. Which gives `TRUE` if the boolean representative is `TRUE` from both expressions, with the order of operations in R, your code get's processed as:

```
(3 == 7) | 5
```

Whereas `3 == 7` gives `FALSE`, but the boolean representative of `5` is `TRUE`, so `FALSE | TRUE` gives `TRUE`.

#### Graph:

Here is a graph (tree) of the way this code gets processed:

```
(3 == 7) |    5
   ↙          ↘
 FALSE   |   TRUE
        ↓↓↓
        TRUE
```

Answer (score 4):

Any value other than 0 is considered as TRUE

```
FALSE|5
[1] TRUE
```

If we do all the precautionary measures i.e. check for precedence by wrapping within `()`

```
> (3 == 7)|5
[1] TRUE
```

because `3 == 7` returns FALSE and by default `TRUE/FALSE` values coerce to `1/0`.  Also, check the `as.logical` coersion

```
> as.logical(c(5, 0))
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```